# Problem With Haskell: print true if all numbers in a list have a difference of more than 2 between them

Tags: loops, haskell

The haskell code I currently have gives an error:

```
main.hs:16:4: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Bool' with actual type `[Bool]'
    * In the expression: map alternateMoreThan2 xs
      In an equation for `function':
          function xs = map alternateMoreThan2 xs
   |
16 |    map alternateMoreThan2 xs
   |    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
main.hs:16:27: error:
    * Couldn't match type `Int' with `[Int]'
      Expected type: [[Int]]
        Actual type: [Int]
    * In the second argument of `map', namely `xs'
      In the expression: map alternateMoreThan2 xs
      In an equation for `function':
          function xs = map alternateMoreThan2 xs
   |
16 |    map alternateMoreThan2 xs
   |                           ^^
<interactive>:3:1: error:
    * Variable not in scope: main
    * Perhaps you meant `min' (imported from Prelude)
```

My code is as follows:

```
differenceCalc :: Int -> Int -> Int
differenceCalc x y = abs(x - y)

alternateMoreThan2 :: [Int] -> Bool
alternateMoreThan2 (x:y:xs:ys)
  | differenceCalc x y > 2 = True
  | otherwise = False

function :: [Int] -> Bool
function xs =
   map alternateMoreThan2 xs

main :: IO()
main
  = putStrLn(show(function[24,21,25,17,50,100]))
```

I have a problem with iterating. It checked the first two pairs before I changed it but stopped at that. Just very confused.
Thanks.

Comment: `map` will return a list of booleans. But furthermore by using `map` you thus will also call `alternateMoreThan2` on any *element*, so on every `Int` in the list.

Comment: Do you mean *all* pairs, or just *adjacent* pairs? That is, should `[1, 5, 2]` pass the test? `1` and `5` are 4 apart, and `5` and `2` are 3 apart, but `1` and `2` are only `1` apart.

Answer (score 2):

`map` will call the function, here `alternateMoreThan2` on each *element* of the list. It will thus for a list of `Int`s `[1,4,2,5]`, try to call `alternateMoreThan2 1`, `alternateMoreThan2 4`, `alternateMoreThan2 2` and `alternateMoreThan2 5`. But that does not make much sense here, since the `alternateMoreThan2` expects a list of `Int`s.

Furthermore `alternateMoreThan2` only will work for a list that contains *at least* three elements. It will raise na exception for lists with zero, one, or two elements.

If you want to check if any two *consecutive* elements have a difference greater than `2`, you should *recurse* on the list, so:

```
alternateMoreThan2 :: [Int] -> Bool
alternateMoreThan2 (x:xs@(y:_)) = differenceCalc x y > 2 && alternateMoreThan2 xs
alternateMoreThan2 _ = True
```

or you can work with `tails` and list comprehension:

```
import Data.List(tails)

alternateMoreThan2 :: [Int] -> Bool
alternateMoreThan2 ys = and [differenceCalc x y > 2 | (x:y:_) <- tails ys]
```

for every two elements, we can use list comprehension as well:

```
import Data.List(tails)

alternateMoreThan2 :: [Int] -> Bool
alternateMoreThan2 zs = and [differenceCalc x y > 2 | (x:ys) <- tails zs, y <- ys]
```

But in that case a more clever ways to check this is first ordering the elements in ascending/descending order, and then check every two consecutive pairs.

In a Haskell program, you thus check this with:

```
main :: IO()
main = print (alternateMoreThan2 [24,21,25,17,50,100])
```